# Probability of Fair Die

Tags: probability, dice

Hi everyone I have a question about probability:
Fair die thrown two times, final score is calculated as follows. If the number on the second throw is a 5 he multiplies the two numbers together, and if the number on the second throw is not a 5 he adds the two numbers together.

What is the probability that C: the product of the numbers is even?

I know how to do it the long way, but there should be a simple way to do it: 
the answer is:

P(C)= 1-P(O,O)= 3/4

Could anyone explain what that means? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. Does the event C have anything to do with the description earlier? C simply asks to find the probability of product of two numbers on dice being even. Then why the redundant conditions of second throw being 5?

Comment: Oh this is the 2nd part of the question, so maybe it doesn't matter here... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the conditions described in first paragraph don't matter.

Now, C is the event of getting an even product. When is product of two numbers even? When either of the numbers (or both!) is even. i.e. the only case when the product is not even is when both of the numbers is odd.

Now, the hint says: $P(C) = 1 - P(O, O)$.

Here, $P(O, O)$ means that numbers on both dice (or on both throws of a single die, whatever), are odd; the event which is easier to calculate.

$P(O, O) = $ Number of first die is odd AND Number on second die is odd.

Since the dice throws are independent, $P(O, O) = P(\text{Getting odd number on first die)} \cdot P(\text{Getting odd number on second die}) = \_\_ \times \_\_ = \_\_$.

Since, it is the complement of this event that we are interested in, we subtract $P(O, O)$ from 1, to get $P(C)$. Thus, $P(C) = 1- P(O, O) = 1 - \_\_  = \_\_$

Now, can you fill the blanks in the above lines to get the desired answer?

Comment: So the odd numbers are 1,3,5: so the pairs are:13,15,35 plus the 11,33,55?
EDIT got it: so 
3(1/6)(1/6)(2) + 3(1/6)(1/6) and 1 minus that gets me 3/4 :D

Comment: So would the working I did be the best way to get the answer?

Comment: @lemonrsiow and 31,51,53

but rather than trying to find numbers, follow the argument in the answer.

Comment: Yes, but there is even simpler way to calculate it.
Since throws of two dice are identical, you just multiply the probability of getting an odd number on the first die with itself, so, $P(O, O) = P(O) \cdot P(O) = \left(\frac{|\{1,3,5\}|}{|\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}|}\right)^2  = \_\_$

Comment: Oh so it's just (1/2)^2 and one minus that? I didn't know I could do it that way...

Comment: Yep, exactly! $\ \ $

Comment: So is it a fact that multiplying the probability of getting an odd number on the first die with itself gets you the total probability of getting both odds in both dice? I can't seem to understand the logic behind it... :(

Comment: Well, not exactly. The second $\frac12$ is for the second (throw of) die, but the way you calculate it for both dice is the same. That's why you can calculate it once, and multiply it by itself because you know the probability is going to be same for the second die. Imagine if there were $100$ dice, you would certainly not want to calculate same probability $100$ times, when you could just raise $\frac12$ to the power of $100$. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Ok I get it now... thanks for your help! :)